# Can I set contents in a folder to be placed in the specific Tier using Windows Tiered storage pool?

Tags: windows, storage-spaces

Say, my `G:` drive is created using the Tiered storage pool. I have 500GB SSD and 500GB HDD. I want to restrict all files in `G:\backup` to the HDD. Is it possible?